# SQL Query: Get number of count

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Need suggestions on a MS SQL query:

table: students

```
id  name    class
--  ----    -----
1   John    Math, Biology
2   Jane    English
3   Mark    Math
```

table: class

```
id  name
--  ----
1   Math
2   English
3   Biology
4   History
```

Desired output

```
name        count
----        -----
Math        2
English     1
Biology     1
History     0
```

Comment: So you have a string column called `class` and in it you need to parse the comma list to get the class names?  I notice in your example `Science` doesn't appear anywhere except in the `Students` table.  Is that a bug or do you really not what that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for SQL Server:

```
SELECT  c.name, COUNT(b.id) as `totalCount`
FROM class c LEFT JOIN
     students s
     ON ','+s.class+',' like '%,'+a.name+',%'
GROUP BY c.name
```

Actually, that doesn't work well with the spaces that you have in the class names.  Try this `on` instead:

```
     ON ','+replace(s.class, ' ', '')+',' like '%,'+replace(a.name, ' ', '')+',%'
```

Comment: I had to use this though: ON s.class like '%'+a.name+'%'

Comment: @FlipBooth . . . That works.  Until you have a class name called "English" and another called "English Literature".

Answer (score 2):

This is for `MySQL`.

```
SELECT  a.name, COUNT(b.id) as `totalCount`
FROM    class a
        LEFT JOIN students b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(a.name, b.class) > 0
GROUP   BY a.name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3798/1)

for best performance, normalize the tables such by creating 3 tables,

students

- ID (PK)
- Name

Class

- ID (PK)
- Name

StudentClass

- StudentID (FK)
- ClassID (FK)

This is a `many-to-many` relationship since students may have many classes while classes have also have many students.

And the query should look like this,

```
SELECT  a.Name, COUNT(b.ClassID) totalCount
FROM    Class a
        LEFT JOIN StudentClass b
          ON a.id = b.ClassID
GROUP   BY a.Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbe2c4/2)

Comment: @JW find_in_set is not a recognized built-in function name.. Im using MS SQL

Comment: @Sable Foste ... I have no control on the DB

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: if that's the case, see @GordonLinoff 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
class.name as name, 
count(*) as count 
from students, class 
where students.class like '%'+class.name+'%'
```

Comment: This won't work because it will not return classes with 0 count